# Open local docx, pptx and pdf in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I'm writing an app which need to support view docx, pptx and pdf in the app. I know the WebBrowserTask can redirect those documents to be opened by approperiate app. However, how can I open those documents if they were downloaded in the isolated storage. It seems that the WebBrowserTask only support http/https protocol, but not local files. Anyways to open those files? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Anyways to open those files?

**No**.

:(

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to do this. The only way to solve this is by having the documents online somewhere and providing the WebBrowserTask with a direct url. Like you already mentioned this does not work with IsolatedStorage.